# What Kind of Regression Do I Need for This?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, prediction

I have a data like this. I need to find 7 predictors' coefficients for the best model to predict dependent. It can only be 1 and 0.

```
A     B     C     D      E      F     G     Dependent
1000  20    -4    150    -567  -83    10    1
-400  35    3     78     341    45    -9    0
```

When "c" stands for coefficient;

Dependent is correctly predicted 1 if cA+cB+cC+cD+cE+cF+cG is positive regardless of the actual number.

Dependent is correctly predicted 0 if cA+cB+cC+cD+cE+cF+cG is negative regardless of the actual number.

I need to get the optimum coefficients for the best model at predicting dependent.

Comment: Is there an experimental design to go along with the data? Are you looking for any interaction effects?

Comment: No interactions. It's linear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).